# OAuth 2 authentication with RESTSHARP doesn't work

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, access-token, restsharp

I am trying to use Restsharp (version  105, also tried newest 106) to connect to REST API. Method of authentication is OAuth 2

I get a token from authentication service but I have trouble using it.
Output request always skips the Authorization parameter.

Request should include parameter like 
**Authorization: Bearer token1235**

```
POST /wares/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: RestSharp/105.0.1.0
Host: localhost
Authorization: Bearer token1235
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Request body:
```

But the **authorization line in the request is skipped every time**.
I tried various ways, but was completely unsuccessful.
Restsharp is manipulating the parameters, which I assign.
**How to include the Authorization parameter with bearer token in the header?**
A guess it must be  pretty standard procedure.

I tried many possibilities suggested in another threads with similar problem but wasn't successfull at all.
For example I would expect one of these should work but it doesn't :

1. client.Authenticator = new OAuth2UriQueryParameterAuthenticator(AccessToken); // this does write 'oauth_token=token12345' text in request body but that's it
2. request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken, ParameterType.HttpHeader); // this does include nothing in the request, there is no parameter at all
3. request.AddHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + AccessToken); // this does include nothing in the request, there is no parameter at all

Comment: Admin, please delete this question because, actually mentioned methods DOES work, i had problem in the process of dumping the header content. 
I have used PHP file for dump and it doesn't produced header as it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the format that you expect, you want to use JWT.

The way to do it with RestSharp is:

```
client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(accessToken);
```

This authenticator produces the authorisation header you want:

```
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.
I had main problem in request dump method. I used PHP as an dumping method and when looking directly through  Wireshark the Authorization header was there!
Thank you very much.